# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: when running main.cpp file (C++)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, architecture, x86-64, atom-editor

I am learning C++ and I am receiving an error when compiling and running my code in the ATOM editor.

This is the following error

```
"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"SavingsAccount::SavingsAccount(double, double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"CheckingAccount::debit(double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"CheckingAccount::credit(double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(double, double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"Account::debit(double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"Account::credit(double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"Account::Account(double)", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"SavingsAccount::calculateInterest() const", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
"Account::getBalance() const", referenced from:
  _main in main-09683f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

I am using a macbook pro please someone help, I think my code is correct as I have checked it multiple times.
There are 7 files all together and I get this message when I compile and run main.cpp

Any help is appreciated.

account.h

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Account{                    //base class account

public:

Account(double);                 //constuctor
void credit(const double);      //adds amount to the current balance
bool debit( const double);      //withdraw money from the account balance
double getBalance() const;      //one data member of type double/returns the balance


private:
double balance;


};


#endif
```

account.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;


Account:: Account(double initialBalance){
    if (initialBalance >=0.0)                       //if parameter balance is greater than 0 set it balance
        balance= initialBalance;
    else
    {
        cout <<"Error initial Balance invalid"; //else say error initial balance invalid
        balance=0.0                                                         //and set the balance to 0.0
    }
}

void Account:: credit(const double money)
{
    balance+=money;                                 //adds amount to balance

}

bool Account::debit( const double money)        //if balance - debit is greater than 0 do it and return true
{
    if (balance - money >=0.0)
        {   balance -= money;
            return true;

        }
    else                                        //else return false and print insufficent funds available
    {
        cout<<"Insuffient Funds available";
            return false;
    }
}


double Account::getBalance() const              //retuns the current balance
{

    return balance;
}
```

SavingsAccount.h

```
#ifndef SAVINGS_ACCOUNT_H
#define SAVINGS_ACCOUNT_H
#include "Account.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SavingsAccount : public Account {             //inherite parent      class Account

public:

    SavingsAccount(const double, const double);         //SavingsAccount constructor
    double calculateInterest() const;                   //calculate the interest

private:
    double interestRate;                            //include a data member of type double indicating the interest rate

};

#endif
```

SavingsAccount.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"

using namespace std;



SavingsAccount:: SavingsAccount(double initialBalance, double    interest_Rate) : Account(initialBalance)       //calls account constructot and then sets interest rate
{

interestRate = interest_Rate;

}

double SavingsAccount::calculateInterest() const        //Member function calculateInterest that returns a double indicating the amount of interest earned by an account
{

double bal;
bal= Account::getBalance();                  //Calls the account class getBalance and sets it to bal and then return balance times the interest rate
    return (bal*interestRate);
}
```

CheckingAccount.h

```
#ifndef CHECKING_ACCOUNT_H
#define CHECKING_ACCOUNT_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CheckingAccount: public Account               //inherit Parent    class Account
{

public:


CheckingAccount(const double, const double);   //checkingaccount     contrucotr 
bool debit(const double);                       //redefins member function debit from account class
void credit(const double);                      //edefins member function credit from account class
private:    
double fee;                             //data member of type double that represents the fee charged per transaction.
};

#endif
```

CheckingAccount.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"


CheckingAccount:: CheckingAccount(double initialBalance, double     feeInput): Account(initialBalance)   //calls account constructor and sets fee to the class parameter
{
fee = feeInput;
}

void CheckingAccount :: credit( const double money)         //redifine
{
Account::credit(money);                             //adds money to the     balance
Account::debit(fee);                                //subrects the fee     from balcance
}

bool CheckingAccount::debit(const double money)
{
if(Account::debit(money+fee))               //call the account debit     function of money +fee. It will either subtract or see if there is enough     funds
{
    return true;                         
}

else
{
    return false;                           //else return false
}

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
#include "CheckingAccount.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"Testing Account Class: Inital balance $100"<<endl;        
Account account1(100);                                              //account constructor is 100

cout <<"Crediting $35.95"<<endl;                //adding 35.95 dolars
account1.credit(35.95);

cout << "New Balance is $"<< account1.getBalance()<<endl;                //printing it out

cout<< "Debiting $200\n";                           //trying to take    200 but it is tooo much so cannot
account1.debit(200);
cout<<"\nDebiting $66.45\n";                        //takes 66.45 so it   works
account1.debit(66.45);

cout << "New Balance is $"<< account1.getBalance()<<endl; //printing it out

cout<<"\nConstructor with insufficent funds"<<endl;          //constucor where balnce is trying to be negative
Account account4(-5);
cout<<endl<<"New Balance is $"<<account4.getBalance()<<endl;        //printing it out



cout<<"\n\n\nTesting Savings Account Class: Inital balance $100 and Interest Rate 10%"<<endl;

SavingsAccount account2(100, .1);                //savings account constuctor $100 and .1 interest rate

cout<<"Interest is $" <<account2.calculateInterest();      //calculate interes

cout<<"\nAdding interest";
account2.credit(account2.calculateInterest());           //adds interest

cout << "\nNew Balance is $"<< account2.getBalance()<<endl;  //printing it out

cout<< "Debiting $200\n";                                   //trying to take 200 but it is tooo much so cannot
account2.debit(200);
cout<<"\nDebiting $66.45\n";                            //takes 66.45 so it works
account2.debit(66.45);


cout << "New Balance is $"<< account2.getBalance()<<endl;//printing it out





cout<<"\n\n\nTesting Checking Account Class: Inital balance $100 and fee $5"<<endl;         
CheckingAccount account3(100, 5);                                   //checking account constuctor with 100 and 5 dollar free

cout <<"Crediting $35.95"<<endl;                            //adds 35.95 with the fee
account3.credit(35.95);

cout << "New Balance is $"<< account3.getBalance()<<endl;                   //printing it out

cout<< "Debiting $200\n";                                   //trying to take 200 but it is tooo much so cannot
account3.debit(200);
cout<<"\nDebiting $66.45\n";                                    //takes 66.45 so it works with a 5 dollar fee
account3.debit(66.45);

cout << "New Balance is $"<< account3.getBalance()<<endl;               //printing it out

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You 're not linking `Account.cpp`, `CheckingAccount.cpp`, `SavingsAccount.cpp`

Comment: Would this mean that there is syntax errors in those files @dim